# Disable Picture in Picture mode in xamarin forms

Tags: forms, xamarin, mobile

In my xamarin.forms project i am using a MediaElement to display a video on my apps welcome page. When i minimize my app, it starts playing the video in PIP mode on ios. Sadly i couldn't find a direct way or a workaround to disable picture in picture mode on ios. Would love some help on the issue if someone came across a solution.

Tried using a custom renderer but that didnt work.

Comment: please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)